# jQuery carousel with drag-and-drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to build a web page with two image carousels and I want to be able to drag images from one carousel to the other.

I have got image carousels working with jCarouselLite: it uses two UL elements to specify the images for the carousels. This works fine.

I can make two UL lists of images with both lists droppable and images draggable. This works fine.

But when I try to make these lists ito carousels, images will not drag outside their carousel. This is because the carousel sets a CSS style 'overflow:hidden' to clip the images not currently visible in the carousel.

I have turned this off while dragging to allow images to drag outside the carousel but then the hidden images are also visible. I have hidden these using an DIV absolutely positioned above and to the left and right of the carousel.

When I drop an image onto a carousel it does not automatically display it so I have the carousel recreate itself when the image is dropped.

here is the code I am using for the drag and drop

```
$( "img.deck_card_draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", 
    helper: "clone",
    containment: 'window',
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 30,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $("div#user_deck_carousel").css("overflow", "visible");
        $("div#user_deck_carousel li").css("overflow", "visible");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $("div#user_deck_carousel").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("div#user_deck_carouselli ").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }
});

$( "div#user_swaps_image_carousel ul" ).droppable({
    accept: "img.deck_card_draggable",
    activeClass: "custom-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    // drop a copy of the image -- this is the required functionality
    var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
        clone.draggable({
            revert: "invalid", 
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });

        $( "div#user_swaps_image_carousel ul" ).
        append('<li style="overflow: hidden; float: left; width: 98px; height: 132px;">'
                +'<div><img width="74" height="122" src="'+clone.attr("src")+'" /></div></li>');
        numSwaps++;
        $("div#user_swaps_image_carousel").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: "#swaps_next",
            btnPrev: "#swaps_prev",
            mouseWheel: true,
            circular: false,
            visible: numSwaps
        });
    },
});
```

All this works but seems hacked together.

My question is this: is there a better way to do this?

Regards and thanks

PBB

Comment: Can you post some code to show how exactly you are implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved by this code:

```
$("li", value).draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Found the code on this page to be quite helpful. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/draggable-item-fixed-to-drag-outside-of-carousel-but-won-t-stick-when-dropped

It doesn't seem like it's a css hack, maybe just needed to play around with the .draggable and .droppable

It fixed my problem and maybe can lend a hand in yours as well.